# After update flutter to 1.22.0-12.0.pre Error package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart': _pendingDimensions': is not true

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, pull-to-refresh

Today after update flutter sdk to 1.22.0-12.0. Wherever the [SmartRefresher](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh) package is used i get this exception in stable and dev chanel but the program works well

```
'package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_position.dart': Failed assertion: line 582 pos 12: '_pendingDimensions': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    MaterialClassicHeader
```

flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 1.22.0-12.0.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.450], locale en-US)
 
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[√] VS Code (version 1.49.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I played with the code a lot but I could not solve the problem
Can anyone give me a solution?

thanks